# Using Sum(IIF()) with multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services

Using the following statement to calculate percentages of multi-category revenue, based on a specific field value `(Fields!CSU.Value="CEG")`

`=sum(iif(Fields!CSU.Value="CEG",cdbl(Sum(Fields!Multi_Cat__Rev.Value)/Sum(Fields!Est_Revenue_000_s.Value)/1000),0))`

This works fine in the current data set that I am using.  I also am attempting to calculate the difference between 2 data sets (same equation) but when I specify the 2nd data set in the function, I get the nested aggregate error (see below)

The expression used for the calculated field `=Lookup(Fields!Opp__.Value,Fields!Opp__.Value,sum(iif(Fields!CSU.Value="CEG",cdbl(Sum(Fields!Multi_Cat__Rev.Value)/Sum(Fields!Est_Revenue_000_s.Value)/1000),0),"dsPriorWeek"))'` includes an aggregate, `RowNumber`, `RunningValue`, Previous or lookup function. `Aggregate, RowNumber`.

I've searched through and cannot find an answer for my issue, please help...

Here is the current way I am attempting to do this:
`=sum(iif(Fields!CSU.Value="CEG",cdbl(Sum(Fields!Multi_Cat__Rev.Value)/Sum(Fields!Est_Revenue_000_s.Value)/1000),0))-sum(iif(Fields!CSU.Value="CEG",cdbl(Sum(Fields!Multi_Cat__Rev.Value)/Sum(Fields!Est_Revenue_000_s.Value)/1000),0),"dsPriorWeek")`

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to place this expression in a textbox on the report, not in a calculated field in the dataset.

Second, you'll need to bring the aggregate functions outside the `Lookup` function. The lookup will bring back the column you need, then you aggregate it.

EDIT:
Nesting aggregates doesn't generally make sense in SSRS. Also, if you're going down the path of specifying a scope in the `Sum` function, you can only specify one group. So you'll quickly run into issues if you are grouping on multiple items in your table.

Based on your clarification, I would suggest that you rewrite the query in such a way that you bring in all the values you need in one dataset. There is limited functionality in SSRS to merge or aggregate across datasets.

Comment: Sorry, This is the error:                                                                                         The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox13’ has an inner aggregate in an outer aggregate that specifies a dataset scope.  An aggregate that specifies a dataset scope cannot contain other aggregates.

Comment: Using this formula:                                                                                      =sum(iif(Fields!CSU.Value="CEG",cdbl(Sum(Fields!Multi_Cat__Rev.Value)/Sum(Fields!Est_Revenue_000_s.Value)/1000),0)) - sum(iif(Fields!CSU.Value="CEG",cdbl(Sum(Fields!Multi_Cat__Rev.Value)/Sum(Fields!Est_Revenue_000_s.Value)/1000),0),"dsPriorWeek")